Multiple url definition with conditions within the same controller for symfony's routing system
Is there a way that I can generate multiple URLs within the same controller that use the same structure?
#[Route('/project/posts/{id}', name:"project-post-view")] //old url
#[Route('/project/posts/{post_ulid}', name:"project-post-view")]
#[Route('/project/posts/{slug}', name:"project-post-view")] // alternative url
function projectViewPost(int $id, string $post_ulid, string $slug, ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
{
    //Function stuff here...
}

The ID url is specifically for legacy emails, where ideally we'd like to forward to the ulid version. Alternatively, if a post uses a slug, it should be in place of the ulid. Is this the format used or how exactly is this defined to fit these conditions?

You have to use Parameter Validation

The requirements option defines the PHP regular expressions that route parameters must match for the entire route to match.

So your routes should look something like this:
#[Route('/project/posts/{id}', name:"project-post-view", 
  requirements: ["id" => "\d+"]
)] //old url
#[Route('/project/posts/{post_ulid}', name:"project-post-view", 
  requirements: ["post_ulid" => "ulid-pattern"]
)]
#[Route('/project/posts/{slug}', name:"project-post-view", 
  requirements: ["slug" => ".+"]
)] // alternative url
function projectViewPost(?int $id = null, ?string $post_ulid = null, ?string $slug, ManagerRegistry $doctrine = null)
{
    //Function stuff here...
}


Curious: does the order matter for these routes?

First one matching will get the job normally in order they are registered. You can add a priority  to routes to change the order.

Error I got: requires that you provide a value for the "$id" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or there is a non-optional argument after this one.

You have to also change the method signature by adding default params.

It looks like having a two routes for a single output doesn't work and that I have to split them into different functions.

Even in the symfony example it shows that having multiple routes for the same function is split into two functions.

No it works, ive done it before. Have you made the args nullable and optional?

Yes, I did, but it seems to not work. No big deal.

@UXerUIer As a workaround you can only inject the Request object instead of url params into the method and then read out params manually.

It really depends on the difference between the parameter patterns, but you can make this work using Parameter Validation as suggested by Code Spirit.
You need to put all three nullable parameter slugs together in one route definition:
#[Route(
    '/project/posts/{id}{post_ulid}{slug}',
    name: "project-post-view",
    requirements: ['id' => '\d*', 'post_ulid' => '([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)?', 'slug' => '.*']
  )]
  public function testMulti(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, ?string $id = null, ?string $post_ulid = null, ?string $slug = null): Response
  {
    return new JsonResponse(['id' => $id, 'post_ulid' => $post_ulid, 'slug' => $slug]);
  }

Also note that the non-optional argument $doctrine must come before all of the optional arguments.
Tested in v 7.2 (dev):

/project/posts/45 returns:
{"id":"45","post_ulid":"","slug":""}
/project/posts/A-45 returns:
{"id":"","post_ulid":"A-45","slug":""}
/project/posts/soupy-soup returns:
{"id":"","post_ulid":"","slug":"soupy-soup"}

Be advised this has the potential to match all three parameters. (This is why I say it depends on the difference in the patterns):

/project/posts/45A-27soup returns:
{"id":"45","post_ulid":"A-27","slug":"soup"}

So if your patterns have the potential to overlap, it will be better to use separate functions.
